# Instagram API get posts by hashtag return URL redirect 302

Tags: instagram

I couldn't use AJAX to fetch Instagram posts by hashtag via this endpoint anymore.
It returns 302.

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/yourTagName/?__a=1
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I am running into the same problem.